# I can't connect VM on GCP as root

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I can't connect VM on GCP as root on the browser SSH.
Is there anyone who had the same problem?
the following message is displayed.
You can drastically improve your key transfer times by migration to OS login.
It might be caused to set a password...

Answer (score 3):

By default, you will login as the GCP user. Now, to log in as root please run the following command once SSH browser works.

> sudo -s

If you cannot login with browser SSH, then I suspect a permission issue with that particular user.
The above is the recommended way of doing things, however if logging in as root is absolutely needed, please follow the steps below:

1. As root, edit the sshd_config file in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

> nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

2. Make sure PermitRootLogin is set to “yes” and save the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.
3. Restart the SSH server:

> service sshd restart

4. Change username to root by clicking on the wheel on the top right corner and selecting “Change Linux Username"